# compare whether value in one column is between two values in another column python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames as follow:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({"value":[3, 7, 5 ,18,23,27,21,29]})

B = pd.DataFrame({"low":[1, 6, 11 ,16,21,26], "high":[5,10,15,20,25,30], "name":["one","two","three","four","five", "six"]})
```

I want to find whether "value" in A is between 'high' and low' in B, and if so, I want to copy the column name from B to A.

The output should look like this:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({"value":[3, 7, 5 ,18,23,27,21,29], "name":["one","two","one","four","five", "six", "five", "six"]})
```

My function uses iterrows as follows:

```
def func1(row):
    x = row['value']
    for index,value in B.iterrows():
        if ((value['low'] <= x) &(x<=value['high'])):
            return value['name']
```

But it doesn't yet achieve what i want to do,

thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to iterate through the values in `A`, and then use `loc` to get the relevant mapped values.  `le` is less than or equal to, and `ge` is greater than or equal to.

For example, `v = 3` in the first row.  Using simple boolean indexing:

```
>>> B[(B['low'].le(v)) & (B['high'].ge(v))]
   high  low name
0     5    1  one
```

Assuming that DataFrame `B` does not have any overlapping ranges, then you will get back one row as above.  One then uses `loc` to get the `name` column, as below.  Because each returned name is a a series, you need get the first and only scalar value (using `iat`, for example).

```
A['name'] = [B.loc[(B['low'].le(v)) & (B['high'].ge(v)), 'name'].iat[0] 
             for v in A['value']]

>>> A
   value  name
0      3   one
1      7   two
2      5   one
3     18  four
4     23  five
5     27   six
6     21  five
7     29   six
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: A = pd.DataFrame({"value":[3, 7, 5 ,18,23,27,21,29]})

In [3]: 

In [3]: B = pd.DataFrame({"low":[1, 6, 11 ,16,21,26], "high":[5,10,15,20,25,30], "name":["one","two","three","four","five", "six"]})

In [4]: A
Out[4]: 
   value
0      3
1      7
2      5
3     18
4     23
5     27
6     21
7     29

In [5]: B
Out[5]: 
   high  low   name
0     5    1    one
1    10    6    two
2    15   11  three
3    20   16   four
4    25   21   five
5    30   26    six

In [6]: def func1(x):
   ...:     for row in B.itertuples():
   ...:         if row.low <= x <= row.high:
   ...:             return row.name
   ...:         

In [7]: A.value.map(func1)
Out[7]: 
0     one
1     two
2     one
3    four
4    five
5     six
6    five
7     six
Name: value, dtype: object

In [8]: A['name'] = A['value'].map(func1)

In [9]: A
Out[9]: 
   value  name
0      3   one
1      7   two
2      5   one
3     18  four
4     23  five
5     27   six
6     21  five
7     29   six
```

I use `itertuples` because it should be a little bit faster but in general this will not be very efficient. This is a solution but there might be better ones.

### Edited to Add:

```
In [8]: timeit A['value'].map(func1)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.5 ms per loop

In [9]: timeit [B.loc[(B['low'].le(v)) & (B['high'].ge(v)), 'name'].tolist()[0] for v in A['value']]
100 loops, best of 3: 9.06 ms per loop
```

Quick and dirty test shows that Alexander's approach is faster. I wonder how it scales.

Comment: Thank you this is what you was getting at. I was using A.apply(func1, axis=1). Why do you use map instead?

Comment: @dleal the `apply` and `map` methods for pandas Series objects are essentially equivalent in this case. However, for pandas `DataFrame` objects `apply` works on entire columns or rows, depending on the axis. If you wanted to use a `Dataframe` method, you need to use  `applymap`. Note that A['value'] returns a `Series` object.

Comment: thanks juanpa.arrivillaga. It does work. I wish it would go faster, but iterrows and itertuple are generally not ideal